# Accordion-like folders on Cocoa for OSX?

Tags: macos, cocoa, accordionpane

I'm an intermediate iOS developer who's trying to jump on the OSX side of things.

I've been struggling to create an accordion-like display of several views, where only one view at a time can be unfolded to occupy the whole parent's view's available space. In other words, click on a view's title bar, it will both open/unfold this view and close/fold the currently open view, with animations'n'all. Oh end, I need the views' contents to be scrollable.

I tried starting from Apple's NSStackView sample code, but first it is not quite what I want, and what's more, I can't figure out how to start from here to end up where I eventually want to be.

Then I tried to master the Auto-Layout facilities but with no success. Truth be told, this whole Auto-Layout thing still confuses me some.

Does any of you have clues as to how I should proceed? Sample code? Tutorials (I tried several Auto-Layout tutorial but at the end of the day they still leave me missing the tricks I'd need to figure...).

Thanks.

/Julian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the sample code: [InfoBarStackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/InfoBarStackView/Introduction/Intro.html). It creates an accordion-like interface, the one difference from what you're describing is it lets multiple views be revealed at the same time (although, that's a simple difference).

It uses NSStackView and autolayout constraints to create the interface and drive the reveal/hide animations.

The stack view could also be put into an NSScrollView to allow the content to be scrollable.  (Something similar was done during a [WWDC 2013 Cocoa Animation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/index.php?id=213) talk).

Comment: Thanks. As I wrote, I already checked this sample code, and it is not quite what I want - or I just don't know how to modify it to my own requirements. In the InfoBarStackView example, the size of a drawer is fixed to the size of its inner view. In a sense, what I'd like to do is the other way around: resize the contained view to the resizable parent's dimensions. Thinking about it, maybe Auto-Layout is my fiercest enemy here, as I don't quite grab the way it should be set up in this specific case.

Comment: By changing the auto layout constraints and the priorities of existing constraints, you should be able to modify it to be what you're looking for. For instance, in the sample each of the content areas have constraints that require them to be that specific content height (you'd want to modify that to allow any height). As well as the vertical hugging priority on the stack view itself: it's currently DefaultHigh, which will cause the stack view to shrink as its panes do, you'll want that to be DefaultLow so it does not. Just with these two changes it's already pretty close to your requirement.

Comment: I'm not there yet, but I got your points and I'm not that far anymore. Great answer. Thanks!